# createUrl Yii - should we call it on controller view, or doesn't matter?

Tags: php, yii

Should createUrl be called on controller or in views ? 
It doesn't matter? Or it does matter ?

Is there a rule we should follow ? Like methods that extend ccontroller should be used on controllers and so on .. ?

Comment: The fact that we can, doesn't mean we should. I'm aware of that. And I'm not concerned about performance on those cases. If we were talking about a view helper, I would agree with last two answers from mjalajel and onkarjanwa. But we aren't I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In View you can use this snippet. You can use this snippet everywhere.

```
Yii::app()->createUrl();
```

But for me is better to define a url in controller's action, and use simply $some_url var in the view.

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function actionSomeAction()
    {
        $params = array(
            'key1' => 'value1',
            'key2' => 'value2',
        );

        $myUrl = Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action', $params);

        $this->render('some_action', array(
            'my_url' => $myUrl
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: as mentioned by mjalajel, its good to use $this->createURL() in view since $this refers to current controller.

Answer (score 2):

both are fine, when you're in a view $this refers to the current controller. So you can do `$this->createUrl()` in either controller or view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use creating url in your view, it does not effect performance because it does not use any database query.
Create Url : Yii::app()->createUrl();
Create absolute url : Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl();

You can use $this to use this functions in your view like $this->createUrl();